# Concatenate Custom Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas, vba

On a daily basis I need to load data to one of our systems. However Excel deletes the previous zeros in front of the contractor IDs. So i have to add THREE zeros manually. I normally use the CONCATENATE function however now the IDs are coming differently so some IDs now only need to have TWO zeros added.

example:

```
ID
911111
```

I use concatenate to make it look like:

```
000911111
```

I came up with the IF formula that detects if the ID starts with a number NINE, to concatenate TWO zeros and if not, then to add THREE zeros.

example:

```
=IF(LEFT(A32,1)="9",CONCATENATE("00",A32),CONCATENATE("000",A32))
```

Now I want to create this formula as a custom defined so I do not have to write down the formula ever time I work on the data every day.

Any suggestions I will really appreciate.

Comment: why not just use `=text(A32,"00000000")` assuming all of them need to be 8 characters, or before you import, have excel treat the column as text (will not truncate the 0's) or put a ' infront of the zeros to excel knows to treat it as text...  It seems to me you're trying to fix the symptom of the problem instead of address the root cause truncation in the first place.  Seems like setting the column to be text instead of numeric or general and it senses numeric on import would solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to use the text formula and the formatting of the cell however, for me to load them to our DB, the IDs need to have the actual zeros in front, if not, the DB will load only the ID without the zeros.

Comment: Entering the IDs in a **text** cell with zeros in front of them will keep the zeros.

Comment: I know Sifu but this list i load on daily basis, several times per day contains thousands of IDs and I pull the data from a DB.

Comment: In the DB is the field from which the data is being pulled and into which the data is being placed a text field or a number field.  If it is a number field, no matter what you do in excel it will lose the leading `00`.  If it is a text field then the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the formatting responses provided in the comments, you could use the RIGHT function to cut off the leading zeroes to the appropriate amount.

For example, assuming A1 holds a string of numbers, between 0 & 9 digits long. We can create text representing a 9 digit string, with as many leading zeroes as necessary, as follows:

```
=RIGHT(REPT("0",9) & A1,9)
```

REPT("0",9) tells Excel to repeat the character "0" 9 times. It then tacks on whatever text is in A1. Then it takes only the rightmost 9 characters of the concatenation.

I generally would recommend the Formatting options noted in those comments, unless you need the text to be 9 characters for other formula purposes.